# extracting date from datetime column

Tags: mysql

If the column TxnDate is datetime type shouldn't the first query work just as the second one?

```
(02:13) mysql>select * from Response where date(TxnDate) = '2010-02-05';
Empty set (0.11 sec)

(02:14) mysql>select * from Response where trim(date(TxnDate)) = '2010-02-05';
...
...
207 rows in set (0.12 sec)
```

I can not reproduce this problem. But the query related to this table is getting affected.
version - 5.0.45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that it has to do something with the bug No. 29898

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=29898